# Not enough free disk space, option for external HDD missing

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, windows-10

I'm currently trying to <s>install</s> upgrade to Windows 10 on my computer which is running Windows 7 at the moment.
As <s>I want to install</s> I'm running the x64 version, one requirement is to have at least 20 GB of free space on the disk which isn't the case (only 2 GB left). There's also no possibility of getting enough space by cleaning the disk or deleting programs.
As I researched the internet, I found a lot of [pictures](http://thewindowsclub.thewindowsclubco.netdna-cdn.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/windows-10-more-space.jpg) showing a Windows 10 installer with the option to aquire additional space by plugging in a HDD/USB stick/SD card which in my case isn't available.

[image]

Did anybody of you encounter this problem yet or do you know a possibile solution to this problem?

Comment: If the image you pointed to directly relates to your situation, it's not true that you're merely installing Windows 10.  You are upgrading to Windows 10.  Is that true?  If so, it's not a standalone installation.  Upgrades are done only on pre-existing installations, so it's not possible to install to another drive.

Comment: Have you cleaned the WinSxS folder? See https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn251565.aspx

Comment: @benJephunneh That's true. The point is that I want to keep Windows 7 for a possible downgrade afterwards. I will correct my question, sorry.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik Cleaning up the disk is not a possibility here as I'm in nedd of more than 18 GB of space.

Comment: @Daniel - I don't understand your comment.  How does running the Cleanup Tool require 18 GB of space?  *In any event your going to need to figure out how to get more free space on the HDD.*  In any event you can be offered the same options by using Windows Update to upgrade to Windows 10.

Comment: click on choose an other drive

Comment: @Ramhound What I meant is that I need 18 GB more of space to have a total of 20 GB free space. And I cannot get 18 GB of space by cleaning up my disk.

Comment: @magicandre1981 That's the issue here. The option to choose another drive as given in the picture is missing in my case.